# Writing csv of list of lists with tuples

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I have this data -

```
data = [[(1,2)], [(1,2)], [(1,2)]]
```

The tuples inside the inner list are co-ordinates.

I've tried this -

```
>>> with open("file.csv", "wb") as afile:
...   writer = csv.writer(afile)
...   writer.writerows(data)
```

The file contains this output -

```
"(1, 2)"
"(1, 2)"
"(1, 2)"
```

I tried reading from this file using this -

```
print [row for row in csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))]
```

Gave me `[]`

And there can be multiple tuples in the inner list.
How can I write this to file as csv, such that another python program can read it?

Comment: do you mean with readable from a csv reader, that you can read it in, in python later on if you need it? or like that openoffice can read it?

Comment: I propose an experiment. To find out if your output is readable by a csv reader, instantiate a csv reader and feed it your output, and see if it works.

Comment: What's supposed to happen where there are multiple tuples in each list?

Comment: @JonClements I don't know. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @svineet what is the data supposed to be used for then... if they're multiple coordinates, is it important that they be in the same row (variable length column CSV file) or should there only be one column of N rows...?

Comment: If only `another python program can read it`, you can use json or pickle instead of csv

Comment: I think @alko is right... if it's purely to be read into another Python program, and isn't needing to be CSV, then use JSON

Comment: I need csv. It's important.

Comment: That output is correct. What do you *want* it to look like?

Comment: When I run your exact code in Python2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04, I get this output: `[['(1, 2)'], ['(1, 2)'], ['(1, 2)']]`.

Comment: @svineet if it's that important it be in CSV, I'm guessing it's also important you should be able to tell us how it should look :)

Comment: Google everything you don't know about after this. See, I'm contributing to Sugar Labs for GCI '13. I am required to export coords of bodies in Physics Activity to a csv file. The mentor says that it should be readable by Chart Activity. So I'm trying to figure out how to write out tuples. But the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want. I changed to data to have more than one tuple on one of the inner lists and have more unique values to aid troubleshooting. The important point is that you must pass `writerows()` a sequence of strings or numbers (or apparently a generator expression producing such things).

```
import csv

data = [[(1,1)], [(1,2), (3,4)], [(1,3)]]

with open("file.csv", "wb") as afile:
    writer = csv.writer(afile)
    writer.writerows((coord for coord in data))

print [row for row in csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"))]
```

Output:

```
[['(1, 1)'], ['(1, 2)', '(3, 4)'], ['(1, 3)']]
```

Comment: Possibly. Or each item of the tuple should be a separate column such that the 1st and 3rd row have two, and the 2nd has four... But, the OP isn't very forthcoming on the exact spec.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import csv

data = [[(1,2)], [(1,2)], [(1,2)]]

with open("file.csv", "w") as afile:
    writer = csv.writer(afile)
    for sublist in data:
        writer.writerow(sublist[0])
```

Comment: You don't understand. There can be multiple tuples in the inner list.